# Why is Bootstrap 4.6.2 modal not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to run a modal from this [site](https://contempglass.org/member-content/). I have Bootstrap 4.6.2 in place and do not get any errors on the page. However, when I try to run the following modal code, nothing happens:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testing">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="testing" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works on the Bootstrap site but it does not work on this page. I cannot see anything that would be preventing it from working correctly. I would appreciate some help in resolving this.

Comment: Where did you include Bootstrap's JavaScript file?

Comment: Thank you. I had an opening comment tag and it was hiding the file.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't the data-target have to match the modal id?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testing">

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="testing" aria-hidden="true">
```

Your data-target should say #exampleModal

Comment: You are correct. In my efforts to modify things I changed the name but got it in the wrong place. Your comment with the one above solved the problem. Thanks.